# What does this phrase mean? 有你真好。

Tags: meaning, phrase

After exchanging thank you and your welcome for doing something nice that I did for someone I received this phrase 有你真好。on WeChat. Google translate says “nice to have you” What does this mean? How should I respond?

Comment: "Nice to have you" = "it's great having you around as a friend/acquaintance/colleague/whatever"

Comment: actually the connotation is rather intimate. More commonly said to close friends or romantic partners.

Answer (score 2):

It means things get easier with your help and they appreciate, or it's nice to have you there because you could help.  You don't really have to response to it. I would just response with a smile in this situation.